# How can I test which of two gameobjects is closest to a third gameobject?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-networking

It would be nice if it was as simple as:

```
    public void Closest() 
    {
        if (A.distance > B.distance) {}
    }
```

But any sort of workaround would be acceptable.

Comment: how do you put code in comments?

Comment: edit your question

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while since I've touched Unity, but this should get you in the right direction. Assuming A, B, and C are objects, and we want to see if B or C are closer to A:

```
var BtoA = (B.position - A.position).magnitude;
var CtoA = (C.position - A.position).magnitude;

// Assume B should return if distances are equal
if(BtoA <= CtoA)
{
    // B is closer
}
else
{
    // C is closer
}
```

Comment: Minor point: you can use sqrMagnitude to skip the square roots in the distance calculations without affecting the determination of which object is closer. The savings are likely to be noticeable only if you're doing this thousands of times in a frame though.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty easy in Unity, as Vector3 has a helper method called [Distance](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html)

Assuming A, B, and C are all GameObjects, you're using C#, and measuring the distance to A, your method can then look something like this:

```
public GameObject Closest()
{
    float distToB = Vector3.Distance(A.transform.position, B.transform.position);
    float distToC = Vector3.Distance(A.transform.position, C.transform.position);

    // B is closest
    if (distToB < distToC) {
        return B;
    }

    // C is closest
    if (distToC < distToB) {
        return C;
    }

    // return null to indicate neither is closest, but you could return C or B, depending on your requirements
    return null;
}
```